# tar extract ignore timestamp

Tags: command-line, software-installation, tar

I create `myarchive.tar` on machine A and use `tar -xvf myarchive.tar` on machine B where tar complains about timestamps : `tar: lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.65.1: time stamp 2023-02-27 20:06:01 is 254449.1210593 s in the future`
Does this mean that the shared lib did not get extracted?
If so, how do I use tar so that it extracts files regardless of timestamps of existing files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-m` or `--touch` option to ignore timstamps in archive, and set modification time to extraction time.

From `tar --help`

```
  -m, --touch                don't extract file modified time
```

So use something like this

```
tar -xvmf myarchive.tar
```